# Changing the toolbar in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to customize the Emacs toolbar with my own images and commands. I have two images for each button, a "disabled" and an "enabled" image. Unfortunately, elisp only provides `tool-bar-add-item`, which allows you to specify a single image. However, the extended menu item syntax for the toolbar has an `:image` property, which can be set to either a single image or a vector of four images, for all combinations of enabled/disabled and selected/deselected. I'm storing my two images in "filename.xpm" and "filename-disabled.xpm", and I've defined a helper function to allow me to easily define new toolbar items in this format:

```
(defun wk-add-toolbar-button (display-name icon definition &rest properties)
  "Add an item to the toolbar
Automatically look for ICON.xpm and ICON-disabled.xpm"
  (let ((images
         `((,(concat icon ".xpm") xpm nil)
           (,(concat icon ".xpm") xpm nil)
           (,(concat icon "-disabled.xpm") xpm nil)
           (,(concat icon "-disabled.xpm") xpm nil))))
    (define-key
      global-map
      (vector 'tool-bar (make-symbol display-name))
      `(menu-item
        ,display-name
        ,(make-symbol display-name)
        ,definition
        :image ,(vconcat (mapcar (lambda (xs) (apply 'create-image xs)) images))
        ,@properties))))
```

But when I call this function, like:

```
(setq tool-bar-map (make-sparse-keymap))
(wk-add-toolbar-button "Build" "c:/Users/William/Desktop/emacs-icons/build" 'smart-compile)
```

my toolbar remains empty.

Adding an image manually, like this:

```
(define-key global-map [tool-bar build]
  `(menu-item ,(symbol-name 'build) ,'smart-compile :image [
    ,(create-image "c:/Users/William/Desktop/emacs-icons/build.xpm" 'xpm nil)
    ,(create-image "c:/Users/William/Desktop/emacs-icons/build.xpm" 'xpm nil)
    ,(create-image "c:/Users/William/Desktop/emacs-icons/build-disabled.xpm" 'xpm nil)
    ,(create-image "c:/Users/William/Desktop/emacs-icons/build-disabled.xpm" 'xpm nil)]))
```

causes the menu item to appear, but then it quickly disappears, with no obvious trigger.

How can I correct this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is faulty:

```
`(menu-item
    ,display-name
    ,(make-symbol display-name) ; <=========== GET RID OF THIS
    ,definition
```

Get rid of the `make-symbol` part and you get what you used manually.  And an icon appears in the tool bar.

You can see what's wrong if you print the result of calling `wk-add-toolbar-button`:

```
(menu-item "Build" Build smart-compile :image
           [(image :type xpm :file "c:/Users/William/Desktop/emacs-icons/build.xpm")
            (image :type xpm :file "c:/Users/William/Desktop/emacs-icons/build.xpm")
            (image :type xpm :file "c:/Users/William/Desktop/emacs-icons/build-disabled.xpm")
            (image :type xpm :file "c:/Users/William/Desktop/emacs-icons/build-disabled.xpm")])
```

That `Build` symbol is extaneous.  You want only the `"Build"` string and the `smart-compile` symbol.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the documentation and thought there was meant to be a string name and a symbol identifier. However, as with the manual item creation, the menu item is not persistent; it disappears after a few seconds. Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: No, sorry.  You would need to investigate further. Maybe start by checking whether the menu item itself still exists, even if the icon is now shown.  Check the `tool-bar` entry in the global map etc.

Comment: BTW, you should be able to just define key `[Build]` in `tool-bar-map`, instead of defining key `[toolbar Build]` in `global-map`. (Not that that changes anything.)

Comment: Actually, it might change something.  It seems that turning `tool-bar-mode` off and back on again resets `tool-bar-map`, unless it is defined.  At least experimenting a bit it seems that defining the key in `tool-bar-map` keeps it there, even after toggling the mode.

Comment: Defining it in tool-bar-map makes the change permanent! Thank you!